# Styling Two Individual Navs

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navigation

I am learning bootstrap 4 and found a navbar via this link: https://carrabbasatlanticcanada.com/

Have really struggled to find a scrollable nav for bootstrap4 that has styles changed on scroll (no logo and position fixed on mobile view).

I have created a navbar like the one in the link that uses 2 seperate navs that are styled so it works the same way: a visible nav and logo, then a scrollable nav with no logo, and fixed nav and logo on mobile devices.

I feel this is quite of a minimal code solution for bs4 and may get around problems with position sticky not working in internet explorer?

I am still fairly new to coding. Is this code OK?
Is it OK to use 2 seperate navs or is there a better solution using 1 nav and some javascript for styling?

Any feedback or possible improvement most welcomed!

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  mynav">
      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    
      <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-       target="#collapsibleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <!-- Navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```
<div id="navbar2">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div> 

<!--Javascript for scrollable nav-->
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 120 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 120) {
    document.getElementById("navbar2").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar2").style.top = "-50px";
  }
} 
</script>
```

CSS:
/*Fixed navbar*/

```
.mynav{
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li a, .navbar-brand{
    color: white;
}

.navbar-toggler{
    background-color: green;
}

/*Scrollable navbar*/
  #navbar2 {
  background-color: #333; /* Black background color */
  position: fixed; /* Make it stick/fixed */
  top: -450px; /* Hide the navbar 50 px outside of the top view */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  transition: top 0.3s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
}

/* Style the navbar links */
#navbar2 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar2 a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/media queries to make the pop down nav disappear on small screens and the hambrger to be fixed/   
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){

  #navbar2{
    display: none;
  }

  .mynav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;

  }

  .top-bar{
    display: none;
  }


.header-area{
  background-color: #000;
  height: 20px;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px){

  #navbar2{
    visibility: visible;
  }

  .navbar-toggler{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: _Is it OK to use 2 seperate navs or is there a better solution using 1 nav and some javascript for styling?_ : Yes it is perfectly okay to have multiple nav bars especially when the markup for mobile and desktop navs are different significantly. I have a wordpress site that has four separate navs, desktop nav, desktop sticky nav, mobile nav, mobile sticky nav.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dorji :) Good to know am on the right track so far with the code.

Comment: If you have 2+ nav bars and the nav items are identical or almost identical I would recommend preventing one from being accessible so keyboard users don't have multiple identical options and will prevent confusion. Add `tabindex="-1"` to each HTML element that should be inaccessible. For more info: [tabindex MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and link!:) Very useful.